# Date conversion from "JAN02/19 to 2019-01-02

Tags: sql, sql-server, 2-digit-year, y2k

How do I convert the values of a varchar(25) column from dates in the format "JAN02/19" to "2019-01-02"(YYYY-MM-DD)?

Comment: Every time you think you've seen every wretched date format people can think of... there's a new one. :-P `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING('JAN02/19', 4, 2) + STUFF('JAN02/19', 4, 3, ''), 6)`. And keep that as a `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) if you can, do *not* try formatting that back to a string in the database again -- that should be the responsibility of the client.

Comment: I would strongly recommend changing the type of the column to `datetime` rather then storing dates as strings. Then you cal let whatever is _displaying_ the dates choose the format.

Comment: Why do you assume that **string** refers to 2019? Isaac Asimov was born in 1920 after all. You have a very serious problem, for which there's no excuse. You should change that field to `date` or `datetime2` as fast as possible

Comment: @JeroenMostert it worked, thank you for your suggestion on not formatting back to string.

Comment: @DStanley thank you for your suggestion for changing the column datatype to date.

Comment: Before converting you should verify what those strings refer to, to ensure you don't change the century by mistake

Comment: Just in case anyone thinks two-digit years aren't that bad, several UK banks' including [Lloyd's systems failed twice because of this already](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/01/02/lloyds_outage/). Also [reported here](https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/lloyds-halifax-bank-of-scotland-online-banking-crash-a4323976.html)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos At the bank, we spent tens of millions of dollars on Y2K.   I was amazed at how deep and pervasive the two digit year was.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti and yet, one of the biggest banks in the world fails in 2020 due to a hacky fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
Declare @S varchar(25)='JAN02/19'

Select try_convert(date,replace(@S,'/',' 20'))
```

Returns

```
2019-01-02
```

Comment: One thing to note: year 58 will be 2058 and not 1958 - just for example (78 also, 88 also, ...)

Comment: @VBoka let's hope the OP hasn't stored any production data yet, and changes the column type instead of just changing a query.

Comment: @VBoka It was not specified, but odds are this is current century.    If not, it would be easy enough to trap future dates.

Comment: That is why I have simply just wrote a small note :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
DECLARE @Date Varchar(10)
Set @Date='JAN02/19'
select DATEFROMPARTS('20'+substring(@Date,7,2),CHARINDEX(@Date,'JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC')/4+1,substring(@Date,4,2))
```

This should give the output in the desired format.

Edit:

To accomodate improper month values:

```
DECLARE @Date Varchar(10)
Set @Date='JAN02/19'
select DATEFROMPARTS('20'+substring(@Date,7,2),NULLIF(CHARINDEX(substring(@Date,1,3),'JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC'),0)/4+1,substring(@Date,4,2))
```

This will return NULL in case the month values are not proper.

Comment: A clear approach -- my only niggle would be that, for an invalid month name, this returns a date with the month set to January rather than complaining.

Comment: Well now it's just clunky. :-) I suggest using `NULLIF(CHARINDEX(substring(@Date,1,3),'JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC'), 0)` to avoid repeating the expression. `NULLIF` and null propagation are nifty.

Comment: Edited the answer to use NULLIF... Thanks for the suggestion @Jeroen